# Is it possible to dynamically change the --limit-rate parameter of curl?

Tags: curl, download, bandwidth

As a followup question to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/153011/10867):

I am using the `--limit-rate` parameter to limit the download speed on computers whose internet is being used:

> curl --limit-rate 10k -r 104857601-209715200 -o distro2.iso
>   'http://files.cdn/distro.iso'

I want to periodically monitor the network usage of each computer, and dynamically decrease the `--limit-rate` once the internet is being used by the user and increase it as the internet usage becomes idle. For now, the only solution that comes to my mind is to restart `curl` with updated `--limit-rate` and `-r` parameter values. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: See [How to change speed limit of running trickle instance](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109973/how-to-change-speed-limit-of-running-trickle-instance/109974#109974) for alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

No, because curl is not interactive. But both `wget` and `curl` have "continue" switches. So you can restart them from the point where you left with new limit rate settings. The following should continue from the point you left.

```
curl -C
```

`wget` has the similar switch

```
wget -c
```

It's also possible to limit the traffic rate using the `tc` and `netem` tools but this will limit the rate for the network interface of the computer. [More info is here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78284/79074).